# OS X Mavericks: Disabling Smart Zoom In Safari?

Tags: safari, macos

“Smart Zoom” is a feature of the new version of Safari in OS X Mavericks and it’s triggered with a simple double-tap on the track pad. Whilst very useful for quickly zooming in and out of websites etc, its also very easy to trigger, which is irritating.

How can one disable this in Safari ?

Comment: This feature's been in OS X since Lion afaik…?

Comment: @grgarside Ah I never had OSX Lion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable Smart Zoom by going to **System Preferences** → **Trackpad** → **Scroll & Zoom** and unchecking the **Smart zoom** gesture.

[image: Smart Zoom]

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in El Capitan; unchecking the box leaves smart zoom enabled in Safari and Chrome, for example

Comment: to be clear, a double tap with fingers close together will not smart zoom, but a double tap with fingers far apart will... very annoying! disabling "zoom in or out" seems to fix this behavior.